# Trying to pass a jQuery mobile range slider value between functions is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, global-variables

How can I make this min variable global in scope so I can pass it to another function? I tried declaring it outside the function but still doesn't work. It will not recognize the variable inside the form submit function.

```
var min;

$( ".minBuyingSlider" ).on( 'slidestop', function( event ) {
    var min = $(this).val();
});

$(".range_form").submit(function(e){
  $.ajax({
    'type': "GET",
    'url': 'loc.php?range=' + min,
    'data': {},
    'success': function (data) {  
      $("#results").replaceWith(data);
    }     
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `min` variable is actually global. In your `slidestop` event handler your [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the one in the global namespace, meaning that it's independent of the other and exists until the event completes. Remove the redeclaration inside of it and you should be good:

```
var min;

$( ".minBuyingSlider" ).on( 'slidestop', function( event ) {
    min = $(this).val();
});

...
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help! You were first so you get the check. Cheers!

Comment: Much appreciated. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring the variable twice,once in the global scope and inside the `slidestop` event also.
Keep it like this,

```
var min;

$( ".minBuyingSlider" ).on( 'slidestop', function( event ) {
    min = $(this).val();
});

$(".range_form").submit(function(e){
  $.ajax({
    'type': "GET",
    'url': 'loc.php?range=' + min,
    'data': {},
    'success': function (data) {  
      $("#results").replaceWith(data);
    }     
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Carl was first so I gave him the answer but you were right there so I appreciate it!